# How to attach a .pdf certificate to an email?

Tags: pdf

I have an insurance certificate that I want to send to specific member, manually or automatically as a .pdf attachment. How can I do this? My question seems stupid but I don't find the way.

With Search contacts, I can find the contact I've identified previously and within "Action:" I can Print/Merge documents but then I download a .pdf when I want to send it instead. I can also send an email using my HTML template with the right Fuzion tokens but it generates no .pdf attachment. So is there a way to combine both?

I saw these posts: [how-can-i-attach-a-pdf-certificate-for-a-membership-payment](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/212/how-can-i-attach-a-pdf-certificate-for-a-membership-payment/) but it's from 2015 and didn't seem successful and [print-pdf-and-send-to-contact](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17754/print-pdf-and-send-to-contact). I'm wondering if there is a simple way to get it done with CiviCRM 5.13.4.

Have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: simple solution is to be found here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31169/6991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the PDF Creation API extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/pdf-creation-api

This extension allows you to send a PDF attached to an email.

Comment: Hi ErikH! thanks for your quick answer. I've already installed this extension. How does it work? How do I use this API? I'm not a developper ;-)

Comment: You use the API normally in code, but if  this is a 1 off exercise you can do so with the API Explorer (Support>Developer>Api Explorer). There will be a PDF entity with create action. You will have to fill in the contact you are going to send it to and the template you want to use. Check if it makes sense?

Comment: I didn't know anything about API explorer. I gave a try and it seems really exciting. I have many questions now! I will open a new thread to learn more about this procedure. thanks Erik for showing the way.

Comment: Be carefull with the API explorer, it is meant as a developer tool not as an addition to the user interface :-)

Comment: ok. thanks I will watch out.

Answer (score 2):

How about saving yet more steps and make it a self-service: i.e. allowing Members to download their own PDF Certificate? I've detailed all the steps on how to do that with Drupal Views in this post:

[How can Members download their own Membership Certificate/Card?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-can-members-download-their-own-membership-certificate-card)

Comment: Hi KarinG! Thanks for this tutorial. It's actually very useful

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm understanding your question correctly.  I'm assuming that you have the PDF document saved somewhere else and that it doesn't require to be amended to suit the individual concerned.

Search for the individual to whom you wish to send the PDF.

In the Actions facility, there is an option to send an email.  Select that and when it's loaded, you'll find an attachments section right at the bottom.  In there you can browse to the appropriate place where your document is saved and attach it to the email.

If you wanted to send it to many individuals and by using CiviMail, there is a similar Attachment facility tab in there to enable the same thing.

If the certificate does require amendment to suit the individual, then you could create a template to include the whole certificate and use tokens to personalize it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi peterb. thanks for answering me. That's what I'm actually doing. And it would be great to have 1 steps instead of 2, especially with 4000 member ;-). I want to amend the .pdf if possible. The ideal process would be : having an html template (document #1) with general purpose and some fuzion tokens and a certificate template (document #2) that also has fuzion fields and is send attached to email with text #1 as .pdf (or any kind of standard file type)

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel how did you resolve this issue? I too have to attach the membership card to the email.Thanks.

Comment: I think it's solved by using PDF API